# How can I update my business' Facebook page via my Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby, facebook

I'm creating a new rails app for my business, and I just finished a new feature where I can put an announcement on the website (for specials, sales, etc.).  I want this announcement to automatically be set to my business' Facebook page.  How can I easily do this?  Is the only way to create a Facebook application, and then if so, can a Facebook application have permissions to edit a business' page (I know apps can edit user profiles, but I don't know about business pages)?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a service called "Twitterfeed" that posts updates from an RSS feed to twitter and Facebook (among other services).  This is a perfect solution for what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

you can always create a rss and use for example rss grafiti http://apps.facebook.com/rssgraffiti on facebook.
i think this is the simplest solution, instead of creating application.

Comment: This helped - thanks! 

The idea of an RSS feed guided my research to twitterfeed, which does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you want, but it'd be trivial to use something like Watir to navigate to the webpage itself and post your status; however, I'm not sure Facebook provides something in their API for direct update.

Comment: Wow, this is a horrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem called 'facebooker', that might help you.

http://apps.facebook.com/facebooker_tutorial/

cheers,
sameera